# Sort <a>s a-z html

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

I am trying to have an ability to sort a bunch of buttons by their contents alphabetically A-Z. I want to make a button that will make them sort. I have seen from other sources (http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/) how to sort Divs with javascript but since these are `<a>` I need help trying to achieve this.

**Edit: This isn't a list of data. I need to scrape from the contents to find the names and sort them.**

html for example here:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton" style="width:202px; text-align:center; margin-bottom: 3px;" id="internetbutton">Surfing On The Internet</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 3px;" id="spongebutton">Sponge Bob Trap Pants</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 3px;" id="sadbutton">Too Sad 4 Me</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 3px;" id="congabutton">Conga</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton" style="width:84px; text-align:center; margin-bottom: 3px;" id="seinfeldbutton">Seinfeld</a>
```

These are just a select few of my buttons. I'd rather try to avoid jQuery as  I have never worked with the library. Thank you!

Comment: try jquery from today. its easy

Comment: This is not a list. These are separate elements. I have looked at that post before. It was not the solution I needed.

Comment: Try this fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xanfar/C2heg/1556/)

Comment: This is awesome thank you!. Is this jquery by chance?

Comment: It works in the fiddle just not on mine. I need to figure out how to import jquery?

Comment: Aha it is jquery gotta add the library. no problem. Thank you

Comment: By george it works :D Woohoo! Thank you.